# Look for existing object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have the following Array

```
[{cityName: "Gauteng"}, {cityName: "cape town"}, {cityName: "Durban"}]
```

I am trying to check if a value matches  **"cityName"** in any of the objects .eg I have a set value as "Durban" and it should return true as Durban exists in on of the objects

My attempt is below however I am getting a false value even if the cityName exists

```
  test() {
   var x = this.getCities;
   var doesExist = x.some((el) => { el.cityName === "Durban"});
   console.log(doesExist);
  }
```

Comment: hi `{ el.cityName === "Durban"}` should be `{ return el.cityName === "Durban"}` or can be just `el.cityName === "Durban". You are very close :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine. Probably your x variable is null. I guess getCities should be a function

```
var x = this.getCities();
```

**DEMO**

```js
let cities = [{cityName: "Gauteng"}, {cityName: "cape town"}, {cityName: "Durban"}];
let isFound = cities.some(t=>t.cityName ==='Durban');
console.log(isFound);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this also

```
let cities = [{cityName: "Gauteng"}, {cityName: "cape town"}, {cityName: "Durban"}];
const index = cities.findIndex(t=>t.cityName ==='Durban');
if(index !== -1 )
  console.log("found");
```

or find as suggested in commen t

```
let cities = [{cityName: "Gauteng"}, {cityName: "cape town"}, {cityName: "Durban"}];
const foundelement = cities.find(t=>t.cityName ==='Durban');
if(foundelement)
  console.log("found");
```

Comment: or even `.find` and then just check for null